# Why I can't retrieve any result when I use mongoose in my app

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/codealong');
```

This is how I connect to MongoDB and when I start to post any data is success but no result and in my browser

just get the result like that 
[ ] 
empty square brackets

This is my dependency

```
"dependencies": {
"body-parser": "^1.18.1",
"express": "^4.15.4",
"mongoose": "^4.11.12",
"nodemon": "^1.12.1"
```

}

here is my server.js file

```
   var express = require('express');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var Vechile = require('./app/models/vich');
    var router = express.Router();
    var app = express();
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    var port = process.env.PORT || 3000
    mongoose.connection.openUri('mongodb://localhost:27017/codealong')
        .once('open', () => console.log('Good to go !'))
        .on('error', (error) => {
            console.warn('Warning', error);
        });

    app.use('/api', router);
    router.use(function(req, res, next) {
        console.log('There is something happens in the Background');
        next();
    });

    //test router
    router.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.json({ messege: 'Welcome to our Api' });
    });

    router.route('/vechicles')
        .post(function(req, res) {
            var vehicle = new Vechile(); //new instance from vehcile
            vehicle.make = req.body.make;
            vehicle.model = req.body.model;
            vehicle.color = req.body.color;
            vehicle.save(function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    res.send(err);
                }
                res.json({ messege: 'Vehcile is READY....!' })
            });
        })

    .get(function(req, res) {
        Vechile.find(function(err, vehciles) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
            }
            res.json({ vehciles });
        });
    });

    router.route('/vehc/:id')
        .get(function(req, res) {
            Vechile.findById(req.params.id, function(err, vehcile) {
                if (err) {
                    res.send(err);
                }
                res.json(vehcile);
            });
        });

    router.route('/vehc/make/:make')
        .get(function(req, res) {
            Vechile.find({ make: req.params.make }, function(err, vehcile) {
                if (err) {
                    res.send(err);
                }
                res.json(vehcile);
            });
        });
    router.route('/vehc/color/:color')
        .get(function(req, res) {
            Vechile.find({ color: req.params.color }, function(err, vehcile) {
                if (err) {
                    res.send(err);
                }
                res.json(vehcile);
            });
        });
    app.listen(port, function() {
        console.log('Server is running on port: ' + port);
    });
```

and this is mongoose module

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var VichSchema = new Schema({
    make: String,
    model: String,
    color: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Vichle', VichSchema);
```

Comment: Really, you have to show us your code.

Comment: 1. Did you check in mongo shell that there are actually records in your mongo? 2. How are you retrieving the documents from MongoDb? 3. Show us code

Comment: i edited the post with code

Answer (score 0):

Just need to change the line of code at save to return both err and data:

```js
 vehicle.save(function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    res.send(err);
                }else{
                    console.log(data);
                res.json({ messege: 'Vehcile is READY....!', data: data })
           }});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your model put

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Vichle', VichSchema);
```

change Vichle by Vechile